# Import pragmas in Ada: How does GNAT know where to look?

Tags: ada

I used this pragma to import `getpid` from C:

```
function Get_Process_ID return Process_ID;
pragma Import (C, Get_Process_ID, "getpid");
```

I expected this to be a little harder. To use `getpid` in C, I need to explicitly include the header file unistd.h; in the above pragma, I made no reference to a header file. How does GNAT know exactly where to find `getpid`?

**Edit:**

Here's a minimum working example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   subtype Process_ID is Integer;
   function Get_Process_ID return Process_ID;
   pragma Import (C, Get_Process_ID, "getpid");   
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Process_ID'Image (Get_Process_ID));
end Main;
```

Saved as main.adb, this compiles with the following command:

```
gnat make main.adb
```

I'm using a fresh install of the `gnat` package from the Ubuntu 18.04 software repositories with no configuration or project files. The GNAT version is 7.5.0.

Comment: It doesn't. You'll have to give the linker whatever information it needs (which libraries or .o files to link, how to find them) somehow, either via arguments to Gnatmake or settings in your project (.GPR) file. Worth saying which version of Gnat and whether you're using gprbuild or gnatmake.

Comment: @BrianDrummond See my edit. I haven't provided any information to the linker whatsoever. Possibly gnat make has some default configuration that points to commonly used C header files.

Comment: "man getpid" says it's in glibc. I guess glibc is a special case, in gcc. For functions in just about anything else, see previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. A detailed explanation is provided in the AdaCore documentation: https://docs.adacore.com/gnathie_ug-docs/html/gnathie_ug/gnathie_ug/the_gnat_configurable_run_time_facility.html#run-time-libraries-and-objects

Comment: Just for a general note, in C you don't "need" that header file.  All a header file provides is a declaration for a function usually.  You can make your own header file or use externs in your C file instead.  In Ada having a procedure/function declaration + the pragma or aspect for import is analogous to your expectation of needing a header file.  As long as you have some declaration using the language's facilities to link that to an external symbol, you can link to any available code that your project can "see"

Comment: Note also pragma `Linker_Options` that allows specifying this sort of information.

Comment: When binding libs in Ada people often define `.ads` along with the lib. The `.ads` file would contain all the pragma import for functions as well as interface types/records (as already said, its pretty much what a .h file is for C). I believe AdaCore has some tools to generate .h <=> .ads. One beauty I find in GNAT stuff, is GPR library project imports magic : just "with" a library GPR into your GPR, and voilà, magic is done, you can only "with" the exposed library Ada files into your own project, and no linker directives to write => compilation and link just works (in most cases)

Comment: generator magic is discussed here for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/61136802/7237062

Answer (score 6):

A detailed explanation is available in AdaCore's documentation on the [GNAT Configurable Runtime Facility](https://docs.adacore.com/gnathie_ug-docs/html/gnathie_ug/gnathie_ug/the_gnat_configurable_run_time_facility.html). By default, a program compiled with GNAT is linked against libc.a and a few others:

> When an Ada program is built, the object code that makes up the final
>   executable may come from the following entities (in addition to the
>   user code itself):
>
> - GNAT Pro run-time library
> - C library
> - Math library
> - Internal GCC library
> - Startup code
>
> The GNAT and GCC drivers automatically link all these libraries and
>   objects with the final executable, statically or dynamically depending
>   on the target and on some compilation options. The `-nostdlib` and
>   `-nodefaultlibs` options may be used to control this automatic behavior.

Compiling my minimum working example with the `-nostdlib` flag fails with the following error (among many others):

```
...
main.adb:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `getpid'
...
```

Functions provided in libc.a might vary by platform. On Ubuntu, you can find libc.a using `locate`, and check to see which symbols are defined using `nm`.

Comment: To emphasize your answer and @Brian Drummond comment, I believe this link might be usefull concerning how to link with libraries other than default ones. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464007/ada-gnat-gprbuild-how-to-link-in-libraries?rq=1